# Convergence test for the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Determine convergence of  the series
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}$$

My proof: using comparison test  I  have

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}  =  \sqrt{n+\frac{1}{n}} - \sqrt{n}  \to 0$$ for large $n$.
Therefore the series should be converges. Now that we need to show that $a_n \lt b_n$ for some $a_n$ s.t $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. for all $n \in\mathbb N$,
$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}} \lt \frac{1}{n^2}$ since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}$ must be converges.

Is this right or I need to fix my $\frac{1}{n^2}$?

Comment: your $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{n^2}$ is wrong for $n\ge5$ . you can use : $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}-n}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n\right)}{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}\left(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n\right)}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}n}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+1} - n}{\sqrt{n}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}\cdot \left(\sqrt{n^2+1} + n\right)} < \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}$

Comment: a little bite more

Comment: so i just need to change $\frac{1}{n^2}$ to $\frac{1}{n^(3/2)}$?

Comment: do i still keep 
$\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{n}}$ - $\sqrt{n}$ =>0

Answer (score 1):

Since $$\sqrt {n^2 + 1} < n + \frac {1} {2n}$$ we have $$\frac {\sqrt {n^2 + 1} - n} {\sqrt n} < \frac {1} {2n \sqrt n}.$$ So the series is dominated by $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {2n \sqrt n} = \frac {1} {2} \zeta \left(\frac {3} {2} \right).$$